# How to download all datastore entities on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, download, google-cloud-datastore

I've read [the GAE docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html), and I can't seem to figure out how to download all my entity data.

What I'd love to do is download the whole thing as a big TSV file (or something I can easily munge into one), so I can import my various entities into a spreadsheet and fiddle with them.

But I'm stuck at the starting gate.  I don't understand the first few bits of the docs: *"This document applies to apps that use the master/slave datastore. If your app uses the High Replication datastore..."* -- I'm not even sure which I have, or how I would tell.

Assuming I have the simpler master/slave, the docs continue: *"...you can use the Python appcfg.py tool by installing the Java version of the remote_api handler..."* but, again, I'm not quite sure what they mean or where I find this appcfg.py tool.

Sorry for such a n00b question, but is there some sort of walk-through?  I just want to download my datastore!

Thanks!

Comment: Installing Java version of the remote_api handler, simply means that you map `com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet` with `/_ah/remote_api` in your `web.xml` so that this servlet becomes available for external tools to communicate with your datastore.

Comment: Here are some details about remote_api: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi.html

Comment: appcfg.py is in [Google App Engine SDK for Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Master/Slave is the default (for now), so that's almost certainly what you're using. You can confirm at https://appengine.google.com/ -> app-id -> Administration -> Application Settings -> Datastore Replication Options.

To download your data, first [install Remote API for Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi.html), then use [appcfg.py to download data](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data):

```
appcfg.py download_data --application=<app-id> --url=http://<appname>.appspot.com/[remote_api_path] --filename=<data-filename>
```

Comment: Link to *Install Remote API for Java* was the clue I was missing.  Also +1 to craftsman's comment for that and to silverfox's for where to find appcfg.py  (Again, sorry to ask stuff that's in the docs, but I was going around and around and not coming up to those links.  Need better readers! :)

Comment: Didn't realize that appcfg.sh (installed with the Java SDK) isn't quite as feature-rich as the appcfg.py (installed with the Python SDK).  To get this to work, I just had to install the Python SDK and it worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you need to do other than just follwiong the google's own documentaion. There is no workaround or walkthrough. I am not sure about java. In python , only thing you need to do is enable remote_api in your app.yaml.

appcfg.py can be found inside the root directory of appengine SDK.