# Google App Engine: How quick are the data dumps?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, benchmarking

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133918/how-to-download-all-datastore-entities-on-google-app-engine) SO article and was amazed to find that no one mentioned how long it takes to run a data dump with the `appcfg.py` tool.

Now, obviously, this is a function of how much data you have, and the hardware your dumping to, but was wondering if anyone had ever benchmarked this. If I have a *decent* amount of data (say, 50GB), how long can I expect to wait for the entire datastore to dump to a YAML file?

Minutes? Hours? Days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The factors affecting time to download a dataset are

1. number of entities
2. size of entities
3. speed of you network.
4. how appengine backend is performing ;-)

I am on a slow link (typically only achieve 150kbps (3G wireless) and my 675MB of entities totalling 1.5million entities takes about 2 days to download to the local machine using appcfg.

So unfortunately there won't be a good hard number you can rely on - you will just have to give it a go and see how long it takes in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you about dumping/downloading to your computer, but I have used Datastore backup, which saves datastore data to Blobstore: I have seen backup speeds somewhere in 100-150MBytes / minute.