# Access legacy GAE Datastore from standalone python

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Trying to find out how to access the GAE Cloud Datastore from outside GAE.  Ideally using a standalone python script (Mac) to run GQL like

```
q = GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = 'test@example.com'")
```

or maybe even a local instance of GAE using GoogleAppEngineLauncher if a standalone script is not possible.

I have done the following

- Accessing an existing App Engine Datastore from another platform (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate) - permissions with service account + private key
- Installed the Python SDK - confirmed SDK files are files are in

  - `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google_appengine`
  - `/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/*** (api,base,client,datastore,...,ext,etc.)`
- Running a print sys.path shows (among other paths)

  - `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google_appengine,`
  - `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages,`
  - `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages,`
  - `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google_appengine,` `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0`
- Did the export

  - `export DATASTORE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT=...`
  - `export DATASTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE=... (full path to .p12 file)`
  - `export DATASTORE_DATASET=...`
  - `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/google_appengine"`
- Ran the example `adams.py` file

  - `Created a new entity called "`Trivia`" with name= hgtg, answer=42 as a record in PROD`

However, running a standalone script

```
from appengine.ext.db import GqlQuery  (or from google.appengine.ext.db import GqlQuery)
```

gives me ImportError:

> No module named appengine.ext.db

I then tried to use a local GAE instance but can't figure out how to connect the PROD GAE database instance.

===

The existing GAE application us using the Datastore (Java) in PRODUCTION.
  In the Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com/project), this would be under `Storage > Cloud Datastore > Query` where I would see the "Entities" (or kind).  Obviously, there is a fairly limited amount of things you can do here and I don't really want to touch PRODUCTION code to run a query.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I don't really see how you can do it. Datastore is tied to your application, so you would need a standalone app ONLY to have your datastore. What are you trying to do exactly? If what you want is a way to use your PROD datastore to test, you'd need to download it and integrate it to your local dev environment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602132/how-do-i-access-my-appengine-datastore-entities-from-my-compute-engine-vm/25603358#25603358

Comment: @Patrice: What I want to do is run a query/report against production data. I don't think the database is too big so downloading it (via remote API? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133918/how-to-download-all-datastore-entities-on-google-app-engine) and loading it up locally might be a possible solution

Comment: You can run such queries in the console safely.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood: Thank you for your note.  I have been trying to figure out where this console is.  On my local GoogleAppEngineLauncher, I create a local GAE "application", go to a browser for the Interactive Console (http://localhost:8000/console) and I see all the imports are there.  From here, I don't know how to connect to the PRODUCTION datastore (I was doing export DATASTORE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT=... on the Mac terminal).  Is there a version of this on the PRODUCTION site (which is running Java)

Comment: console.developers.google.com should bring you to your console

Comment: then https://console.developers.google.com/project/YOURPROJECTNAMEHERE/datastore/query is where you can run queries.

Comment: @Patrice @PaulCollingwood: Thank you for working with me on this ... the developer console was the first thing I tried but the most you can do here it get the Filters going but not run anything like a `GqlQuery` (basically what is here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference).  Maybe I am trying to make this too much like SQL :(